# JS live highlighting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I a trying to make css editor in JS as jquery plugin.
So far i managed to make static highlighter. 
"That" is $(editable div)

```
 var temp = '';
        var re = /([^{}]+)\s*{/g;
        while (m = re.exec(plainCss))
        {
            var end = plainCss.indexOf('}', m.index + m[1].length);
            temp += '<span class="selector">' + plainCss.substring(m.index, m.index + m[1].length) + '</span>';
            temp += '<span class="brace">{</span>';
            temp += '<span class="body">' + plainCss.substring(m.index + m[1].length + 1, end) + '</span>';
            temp += '<span class="brace">}</span>';
        }
        that.html(temp);

        that.find('.body').each(function(i, elem)
        {
            var text = $(elem).text();
            var re = /([^:;]+):([^:;]+);/g;
            var temp = '';
            while (m = re.exec(text))
            {
                temp += '<span class="rule">' + m[1] + '</span>';
                temp += '<span class="colon">:</span>';
                temp += '<span class="value">' + m[2] + '</span>';
                temp += '<span class="semicolon">;</span>';
            }
            $(elem).html(temp);
        });
```

Now i want to make it highlight live, while typing. I registered keypress event, determine which "scope" is user in (selector,body(rule,value)) and wrap written character accordingly.
Problem is caret position in editable div. For example. When user clicks in

```
<span class='semicolon'>;</span>
```

and writes something, i block that event, insert `<span class='rule'>{new_character}` after that and cursor(caret) position is where it was last time.
I tried some jquery plugins for caret manupulation, but nothing really worked...
I am not shure if is this good approach, what would you do to make live highliter work ?

Comment: You may check this one http://codemirror.net/

Comment: What is better way ? Figure out how to convert html 2 text and visa versa without loosing identation, somehow hack saving and resoring caret position, then redrawing all (from text to spans)

OR

parsing only first time, then manipulating dom on keypress event (i am doing that for two days, nearly 1000 lines of code)

Comment: @KryštofHilar, how much amount of text do you need to be able to handle smoothly? There are simple ways, and there are efficient ways to handle this.